# Escaping square bracket inside variable for grep querystring inside of shellscript

Tags: shell

I have searched all answers (there are lots) but none of the solutions work with the code I am trying to implement. I am having troubles with the following code:

```
win_string="\\\[something]\\\[somethingelse] somethingelseelse:"

# if a valid pair has been found, stop the loop 
if [ $(cat somefile.txt | grep "$win_string") != "" ];then
    echo
echo "**********WIN!**********"
    cat somefile.txt | grep "$win_string"
echo "**********WIN!**********"
echo
    exit 0 
fi
```

Let's say that somefile.txt contains a bunch of garbage on every line and we are searching for the line:

```
[something][somethingelse] somethingelseelse:
```

When I cut and paste it into a terminal it works fine, however when I put it in a shellscript I get the following error:

```
helloworld.sh: 146: [: !=: unexpected operator
```

I know it has  to have something to do with the [ and ] within my search query, and initially there was no $win_string variable, I just added it in as an attempt to solve the problem...

Comment: Please stop adding thanks or signatures again. Read [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: [No Thanks, Damn It!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it). It's not niceness, but rather noise to people reading the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to store the result of the grep and then do the if comparision.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                      

win_string="\[something]\[somethingelse] somethingelseelse:"     

# if a valid pair has been found, stop the loop                  
result=$(cat somefile.txt | grep "$win_string")                  
if [ "$result" != "" ];then                                      
   echo "**********WIN!**********"                               
   cat somefile.txt | grep "$win_string"                         
   echo "**********WIN!**********"                               
   exit 0                                                        
fi
```

In a short test this works for me.

Comment: F@#*$ I _never_ thought of that! I try it now and accept it (I am sure it works but I test first) HUGE thanks, been mucking with this for a few hours :D

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @cb0 's answer, because I really spent a while looking for a solution to this, if you needed to escape a string from a passed parameter to the script, you could use the variable replacement bashism:

***script.sh***:

```
#!/bin/bash                                    

result=$(cat somefile.txt | grep "${1//\[/\\[}")
if [ "${result}" != "" ];then
   echo "**********WIN!**********"
   echo "${result}"
   echo "**********WIN!**********"
   exit 0
fi
```

`script.sh '[hello]world'`